# Can the Johnson-Lippmann operator be used to calculate the Lamb shift

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

The Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector which is conserved for a Newtonian (1/r) potential can be used to calculate higher order potential General Relativity effects such as the precession of Keplerian orbits (see e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712082).  In 1950 Johnson and Lippmann described the Dirac equation operator version of the LRL vector (see https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0508122).  Can the conservation of the JL operator to zeroth order similarly be used to calculate the value of the Lamb shift?